# Opening file in C++ on Unix: can we avoid case sensitivity?

Tags: c++, unix, manjaro, sdl-ttf

I am opening a file in a C++ program in Manjaro:

```
 TTF_Font* result = TTF_OpenFont(filename, point);
```

(It's using SDL2_TTF, so I don't have direct access to the function that does the opening, but bear with me.)

The font package (Microsoft Core Fonts for the Web, ttf-ms-fonts) has names in all lower case on other distributions ("arial.ttf"), but with caps put in sort of randomly in Manjaro ("Arial.TTF"; "Trebucbd.ttf"; "trebucbi.ttf").

Is there a way I can tell C++ to find *any* file that matches my filename, w/o regard to case? If there is, maybe I can identify the capitalization it uses and then load that version.

Comment: It's a C question, but I don't think there's anything in C++ that fundamentally changes the appropriate answer.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. But you can (programmatically) read all the font files in the folder, then select the one you want.

Comment: Use a combination of [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) and [`<regex>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)?

Comment: There are also things on the file system. Not all file systems are case sensitive. But I am not an expert on this, just remember running into the issue many years ago.

Comment: IMHO the simplest and most robust way is to rename every relevant file to a consistent case pattern (all lower case, all upper case, capitalize. etc.)